# CodeIgniter Form Validation Set Message away from Controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, object, configuration

I have the current code in my Controller:

```
$validated=$this->form_validation
    ->set_message('required',lang('form_error_required'))
    ->set_message('valid_email',lang('form_error_email'))
    ->run()
```

The rules are saved in my Form Validation Config file.

It works perfectly as is, but I personally find that these should not be present in the Controller (nor in a Model).

I would like to know if it is possible to save these set_message in a config file as well, or, better, how to override the existing "required" and "valid_email" lines without changing the language files in the system folder.

I tried including the "required" and "valid_email" lines in my language file, and change the order in which the Form Validation Library and my Language files were loaded - it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Look at system/language/english/form_validation_lang.php.

Copy it into application/language/yourlang/ and of course, translate the strings inside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had tried this as well and it did not work either.

Comment: That's strange. I just tried with a fresh install of CI and it worked well. Have you changed the default lang in your config file ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

```
  //path to config file
 ../application/config/form_validation.php
```

Then my construct:

```
 $this->load->library('form_validation');
```